# sub domain htaccess redirect to HTTPS URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been trying to redirect my subdomain `buynow.mydomain.info` to the product link which is `https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=******&quantity=1&product_id=1`.

I tried the simple .htaccess line

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=******&quantity=1&product_id=1
```

but it doesn't work, it only redirects to `https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase` without mentioning my product as it ignores the rest of the URL `?sid=******&quantity=1&product_id=1`

I thought it might be a problem with the link which is HTTPS, but I can't solve it, I hope you guys could help me, thanks.

Comment: Your rule works, however, `2checkout.com` itself redirects away from that page. You might want to ask them why. Perhaps a wrong / unknown sid?

Comment: Oh, and according to their docs..... it's `spurchase` in that url, not `purchase`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=******&quantity=1&product_id=1 [R=301]
```